# How to redirect output to memory instead of file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I can redirect the output to a file like according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) like this.

> $PROFILE > FileOfPro.txt

Sometimes, I'd like to catch it to the memory for pasting elsewhere. There's the manual option of selecting the text and copasting (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>) but it would be much more impressive and convenient to snatch the output to the memory directly.

Is it possible? I haven't found info on redirecting to memory (perhaps due to poor choice of key phrases).

Comment: it's already in memory. [*grin*] however,  if you want to send data as text to the clipboard, take a look at `Get-Help *clip*` for a couple of hints.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Good suggestions. Would you like to post it as an answer to be accepted? You might want to throw in *$PWD | CLIP* as an example of my case and mention also that *CLIP* isn't any alias of PowerShell (checked by *Get-Alias c\**). Also, I'm getting the whole paragraph that *$PWD* produces, while I'd like to get the path of current working directory only. Any hints in that regard?

Comment: you can get JUST the value of the path from `$Pwd` by using `$Pwd.Path` ... [*grin*] as for an answer - it looks like `Wasif Hasan` has already covered what i mentioned. thank you for the offer, tho!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Nevermind. I already snatched your wisdom and put it into his reply. I sensed you were laz... hrmp... smart not to do it yourself.   :)

Comment: i'm glad to have helped ... and thanks for adding the updated info to the Answer so that others will be able to see & use it! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy text to clipboard using this command:

```
Set-Clipboard -Value "Any thing"
```

Or

```
Set-Clipboard -Value $Variable
```

And if though you copy text to file it is still in memory, the copied text is stored inside clipboard. Another approach is using the command *CLIP*, as follows.

```
$PWD | clip
```

The above, copies the **entire** output of the command into the clipboard. If you need the line with the actual path of the current working directory, the below will do the trick.

```
$PWD.Path | clip
```

After that, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> produces the line with the path.

Comment: I took the liberty to update your answer with the comments from the other guy. He seemed resilient to the idea of providing a full answer and I feel that both his and yours make a great complement to each other.